# Delete substring between delimiters in python

Tags: python, string, delimiter

Is there an efficient way to delete a substring between two delimiters in python? For example from

```
"This $\textbf{word}$ must be deleted"
```

to obtain

```
"This must be deleted"
```

If possible, I would rather not use the regular expression package.

---

Also, what if the delimiters are not equal, e.g. from

```
"This {word} must be deleted"
```

to obtain

```
"This must be deleted"
```

Comment: regex `re.sub("\$.*?\$\s+","",s)` that should work

Answer (score 2):

You could do something along the following lines if you do not want to use regular expressions:

```
s = "This $\textbf{word}$ must be deleted and this $here$ too"
d = '$'

''.join(s.split(d)[::2])
# 'This  must be deleted and this  too'
```

This splits on the delimiter and only keeps every other token. If you want to get rid of double spaces, you can do:

```
' '.join(x.strip() for x in s.split(d)[::2])
# 'This must be deleted and this too'
```

Comment: @Jean-FrançoisFabre Added a variant. `rstrip` or `lstrip` might behave awkwardly if there is a replacement token at the beginning or end.

Answer (score 1):

You could do some `str.partition` like,

```
>>> x = "This $\textbf{word}$ must be deleted"
>>> first, _, rest = x.partition('$')
>>> _, _, rest = rest.partition('$')
>>> ' '.join([first.strip(), rest.strip()])
'This must be deleted'
```

Answer (score 1):

With [`str.index`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#str.index) feature:

```
s = "This $\textbf{word}$ must be deleted"
pos = s.index('$')
res = s[:pos] + s[s.index('$', pos + 1) + 1:].strip()
print(res)   # This must be deleted
```

---

For *symmetric* delimiters:

```
s = "This {word} must be deleted"
res = s[:s.find('{')] + s[s.rfind('}') + 1:].strip()
print(res)   # This must be deleted
```